# shake a textbox if validation fails using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to verify the input values in 2 textboxes. If they match, the user can proceed else the textbox shakes. However, I am not able to do so. Please help.

This is what I had tried:

```
$("#signupbtn").click(function(){
    var x,y;
    $("#password").focus(function(){
        x = $("#password").val();
    })
    $("#password2").focus(function(){
        y = $("#password2").val();
    })
    if(x!=y)
    {
        $("#password2").effect("shake")
    }
})
```

Comment: So with the code you've posted, what doesn't work?

Comment: Remove your `.focus(...)` wrappings, just keep the assignments. Also make sure jQuery UI is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JQuery-UI to get the shake effect. Below is an example of it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login_button").click(function() {
    if ($("#password1").val() != $("#password2").val())
      $("#login").effect("shake");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form id="login" name="login">
  <h3>Login Form</h3>
  <input class="password" id="password1" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
  <input class="textbox" id="password2" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
  <input id="login_button" type="button" value=" Login ">
</form>
```